# How do I query a class Name when it is dynamically declared

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below, I am trying to initialize a class name dynamically every time the `for loop` iterates. 
How do I query it without parenthesis?

```js
$("#grid-input").click(function() {
  $(".drawing-area").empty();

  var rows = $("#row").val();
  var cols = $("#col").val();
  if (rows > 0 && cols > 0) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
      $('<tr>').appendTo('.drawing-area').addClass('row' + i); //Dynamically declared class
      var className = 'row' + i; //Tried storing it in a variable
      for (var j = 1; j <= cols; j++) {
        $("."className).append('<td id="myPixel" width="20px" height="20px" style="border: 1px solid #000;"></td>'); //How do I query it here?
      }
      $(".drawing-area").append('</tr>');
    }
  } else {
    alert("You haven't provided the grid size!");
  }
});
```

Comment: `$("." + className)`   You were missing the `+`

Comment: Used the 'tidy' snippet function and it showed where the code error was (had to revert that part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery selectors take an string as param, so you just need to properly pass this string. In your case you are missing the + operator to concat the strings. So Simply try.

```
$("."+className)...
```

instead of your code

```
$("."className)...
```